# Using $watch without $scope ( controller as syntax)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

In Angular 1.3 it's possible to use `this.foo='bar'` insteaod of `$scope.foo='bar'`. Now, how can I use `$watch` without $scope?

Comment: The short answer seems to be no, because $watch is a $scope method, but elaborate: What's the use-case, what is the scope of the variable you want to observe?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do you can use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) if you just need to observe a change on an input field

Comment: Indeed I need to watch any change to any filed of a model.

Comment: `$watch` has very specific abilities, [here are some examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29189252/1175496) , the most powerful use-case involves `$watch(.., .., true)` on an array, which detects array re-assignment, array modification, and array element modification. Can `ng-change` replace this ability?

Answer (score 19):

There are several options to avoid having to use `$watch` when using the `controller as` syntax.

The following examples are taken from a [blog post I wrote about avoiding `$scope`](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html).

**Using `ng-change`**

> If you have a watch set up to listen for a property change that
>   originates from a form field, then ng-change is your best bet.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name" ng-change="ctrl.search(ctrl.name)" />

MyCtrl.prototype.search = function(name){
  //call some service here
};
```

**Using ES5 Properties**

> If you have some property that isn't bound to an input field, or is
>   going to be updated from code, it may seem like a watch is your only
>   choice. However, if you don't have to support IE8 or lower, then you
>   can take advantage of ES5 properties to trigger functionality when
>   something changes on your controller.

```
var MyCtrl = function(){
  this._selectedItem = null;
};

Object.defineProperty(MyCtrl.prototype,
    "selectedItem", {
    get: function () {
        return this._selectedItem;
    },
    set: function (newValue) {
        this._selectedItem = newValue;

        //Call method on update
        this.onSelectedItemChange(this._selectedItem);
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: The ES5 solution does not work for changes in nested objects, though.