# bindToController how to get rid of all the $scope ($scope.$on)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm implementing an AngularJS directive on Angular 1.4.12 using the controllerAs and bindToController "pattern" in order to have a clean controller which doesn't depend on $scope.
However I still find hard to get rid of $scope on these lines:

```
$scope.$on( '$destroy', function() {...} );
$scope.$on( '$stateChangeSuccess', function() {} );
```

Any idea how to handle this case?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344131/using-watch-without-scope-controller-as-syntax

Comment: I read that the lifecycle hooks have been introduced in Angular 1.5.x. Probably that is what I'm looking for. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile. Unfortunately I can't upgrade my project to AngularJS 1.5.x

Comment: lifecycle hooks are currently only available to components

Comment: you will have to keep using $scope for events... its kind of service providing you these services

Comment: @svarog They are available in directives. Components are sugared directives.

Comment: See this https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-component. But as the answer already says, there's no valid reason to zealously eradicate $scope. `$scope.$on` is the way the events work in Angular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind not using $scope is to:

- not pollute the HTML with variables that have no context and potentially have conflicting variable names in the same scope.

  ng-model="name" VS ng-model="userController.user.name"
- not pollute you javascript code by preceding every variable and
  function with $scope

If you need to broadcast events or watch changes, it's perfectly fine to use $scope (especially if you have no alternative like .components in angular 1.5)

See `$scope` as a service provided to you by Angular just like `$window` or `$state`.
If you need it, you can use it. (but don't go and put code in there, even if you can)

Comment: You are spot on. The only addition I would make is that the new ui.Router deprecates the $stateChangeSuccess event in favor of a onSuccess subscription hook: https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onsuccess

Comment: Thanks for point out the deprecation. Unfortunately we're currently using ui-router v 0.2.15 which doesn't offer the possibility to hook into onSuccess